# Como eu posso passar mais de um ponto para o google maps nesse while?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, google-maps

Queria marcar todos os pontos onde a distância aproximada é menor que 25 km, mas ele nem mostra o primeiro ponto que é o mais próximo(4km), mostra logo o ultimo (18km). Segue o que vem do meu banco:

> ```
> Array ( [0] => -22.356472 [latitude] => -22.356472 [1] => -47.361216 [longitude] => -47.361216 ) 0    
> Array ( [0] => -23.479701 [latitude] => -23.479701 [1] => -47.447751 [longitude] => -47.447751 ) 125    
> Array ( [0] => -23.479701 [latitude] => -23.479701 [1] => -47.447751 [longitude] => -47.447751 ) 125    
> Array ( [0] => -23.479701 [latitude] => -23.479701 [1] => -47.447751 [longitude] => -47.447751 ) Distância 125    
> Array ( [0] => -22.384003 [latitude] => -22.384003 [1] => -47.378910 [longitude] => -47.378910 ) Distância 4    
> Array ( [0] => -22.906058 [latitude] => -22.906058 [1] => -47.063822 [longitude] => -47.063822 ) Distância 68    
> Array ( [0] => -22.483987 [latitude] => -22.483987 [1] => -47.449943 [longitude] => -47.449943 ) Distância 17    
> Array ( [0] => -22.368794 [latitude] => -22.368794 [1] => -47.533523 [longitude] => -47.533523 ) Distância 18
> ```

.php:

```
<?php
    include('dcclinicas/include/conexao.php');
    $idUsuario = '7';

    $lat = $link->query("SELECT latitude FROM usuarios WHERE id ='$idUsuario'")->fetch_assoc();
    $long = $link->query("SELECT longitude FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'")->fetch_assoc();          

    $dados = $link->query("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM usuarios");

    while($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($dados)){
        $distancia = distanciaPontos($lat['latitude'],$long['longitude'], $cont['latitude'], $cont['longitude']);
        echo "<br>";

        if($distancia <= '25'){
              $latDestino = $cont['latitude'];
              $longDestino = $cont['longitude'];    

              echo '<script type = "text/javascript">  
                      function loadMap() {
                        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                          var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                          map.setCenter(new GLatLng('.$lat['latitude'].', '.$long['longitude'].'), 6);
                          var markerAtual = new GMarker(new GLatLng('.$lat['latitude'].','.$long['longitude'].'));
                          var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng('.$latDestino.', '.$longDestino.'));

                          map.addOverlay(markerAtual);
                          map.addOverlay(marker);
                        }
                      }
                    </script>';
        }
        $cont++;
        print_r($cont);
        print_r(" ".$distancia);

    }
```

Comment: Lembrando que eu quero mostrar todos os pontos que estão a menos de 25 km. Obrigado ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Você está gerando vários mapas com esse código, todos eles sobrescrevem o último, por isso só está retornando o último ponto.

Seu loop deveria estar depois de `var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));` se não ele cria outro mapa.